# How to apply github commit patches in Magento 2 using composer?

Tags: magento2, patches

I've created a new module with a `composer.json` file:

```
  "extra": {
      "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
      "patches": {
          "magento/framework": {
              "TransportBuilder doesn't add 'to' email-addresses, if given in an array": "https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be5455a58240b57e4dc0c44a5cea2bb5a2e01c57.diff"
          }
      }
  }
```

And what I want to achieve is to apply that change from that commit to this file: `vendor/magento/framework/Mail/Template`, when i install my module .

By doing a `composer require mymodule`, my module is installed, but the patch is not applied. I also use this package: `cweagans/composer-patches` as the [docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/patching.html#custom-patches) suggested. What do i miss ?

[UPDATE] - Same If i change the url from ....diff into

```
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be5455a58240b57e4dc0c44a5cea2bb5a2e01c57.patch
```

I am getting:

```
    https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/be5455a58240b57e4dc0c44a5cea2bb5a2e01c57.patch (TransportBuilder doesn't add 'to' email-addresses, if given in an array)
patch '-p1' --no-backup-if-mismatch -d '/Users/attilanaghi/Development/local/vendor/magento/framework' < '/var/folders/rd/rg6xy_fs00bgwvmbpw2myyrr0000gn/T/5e1716d50d06b.patch'
can't find file to patch at input line 15
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
.....
```

[UPDATE] . I am trying to use the extra/map. See: https://github.com/magento/magento-composer-installer . But so far without any luck. Any ideas how can i apply my patch ?

```
  "type": "magento2-module",
  "extra": {
    "magento-force": true,
    "map": [
        [
            "patches/github_issue_25453.patch", "patches/github_issue_25453.patch"
        ] 
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to add like that in composer.json file

```
"scripts": {
        "post-install-cmd": [
             "patch -p1 < custompatch.patch" 
        ]
    }
```

Then run command

```
composer update
```

Comment: i see you added the .patch extension. That means i need to create that file, cannot i just use a github commit ? like it is in my description ?

Comment: can you check my post update ?